# How to get properly scaled forward slash delimiters?

Tags: delimiters

I had originally thought this was related to my choice of font, but it seems like forward slash delimiters even in the default math font don't scale properly (or, at least, not as expected). For instance:

[image]

They're definitely larger than the normal size, but don't fully enclose the array as expected.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    $\left/\begin{array}{c}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_3\\a_4\end{array}\right/$
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get forward slash delimiters that will scale up to the full size of the thing they enclose, like with parentheses, brackets, braces, etc.?

My actual use case is writing up some exercises for students that use phonological features, which I want to represent between two forward slashes, like this:

[image]

This works okay until I need to have more than 2-3 features (really just 2, but with 3 the result is passable):

[image]

I would ideally like to not have to manually decide how big to make these forward slashes for each set of features using `\fontsize` or anything like that, as that would end up being quite time-consuming.

(An even better solution would be one where the forward slash delimiters are scaled only vertically, so that as they grow they don't end up taking excessive amounts of horizontal space. But maybe that's not feasible without putting everything in a `tikzpicture`.)

Comment: There is a maximum size for `/`. “Verticel” delimiters such as `{` or `[` can be extended at will because after a maximum size corresponding to a glyph in the math font, the bigger sizes are constructed with repeaters.